# XPath to select div with single child ignoring whitespace?

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I would like to find unneeded nested divs and clean them up by looking for a div which has only a single element (ignoring whitespace nodes).

```
<div>
    <div>Text in nested div</div>
</div>
```

So far I have the following xpath which seems to partially work.

```
//div[count(node()[normalize-space()]) = 1]
```

Comment: In what way does it partially not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this short and efficient expression**:

```
//div[*[1][self::div]][not(*[2]|text()[normalize-space()])]
```

Comment: So what is that saying? If the first element is a div, and the second one doesn't exist or is an empty element?

Comment: @Xeoncross, This says that the first child element must be a `div` and there shouldn't be second child element, and there shouldn't be any non-whitespace-only text-node children. The efficiency is that the child elements are not "counted and only then compared to 1". Imagine having many `div`s with hundreds of child elements ...

Comment: `not(*[2]|text()[normalize-space()])` means no second element or a second element that is empty (after the whitespace is removed).

Comment: @Xeoncross: Actually no. It means: There isn't a second element-child and also there isn't any text-node child that contains any non-white-space characters. The `|` character is the XPath union operator.

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
//div[not(*[2]) and div and not(text()[normalize-space()])]
```

This should select `div`s that have a single child element and no non-whitespace child text nodes.

Comment: Seems to work great with one small change to only select child divs. `//div[count(*) = 1 and child::div and not(text()[normalize-space()])]`

Comment: Excellent. One thing to note is that you don't need the `child::` before the `div` in this case. Just using `//div[count(*) = 1 and div and not(text()[normalize-space()])]` will work exactly the same, because the child axis is the default axis.